I'm returning file for every type instead of file, subdirectory, etc of a folder. How can I fix this?
import os
import hashlib
import time

# Python 3rd Party Libraries
from prettytable import PrettyTable     # pip install prettytable

# Psuedo Constants
targetFolder = input("Enter Target Folder: ")

# Start of the Script
print("Walking: ", targetFolder, "\\n")
tbl = PrettyTable(\['AbsPath','Type', 'FileSize', 'UTC-Modified', 'UTC-Accessed', 'UTC-Created', 'SHA-256 HASH'\])

for currentRoot, dirList, fileList in os.walk(targetFolder):
for nextFile in fileList:          
fullPath = os.path.join(currentRoot, nextFile)     
absPath  = os.path.abspath(fullPath)          
   if os.path.isfile(absPath):         
fileType = "file"     
elif os.path.isdir(absPath):         
fileType = "Directory"     
elif os.path.islink(absPath):         
fileType = "link"     
else:         
fileType = "unknown"              
fileSize = os.path.getsize(absPath)     
stats = os.stat(absPath)     
timeLastModified = stats.st_mtime    
 humanTimeLastModified = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(timeLastModified))             timeLastAccess   = stats.st_atime     
humanTimeLastAccess = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(timeLastAccess))     timeLastCreated = stats.st_ctime     
humanTimeLastCreated = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(timeLastCreated))          
        with open(absPath, 'rb') as target:                  
               fileContents = target.read()                 
               sha256Obj = hashlib.sha256()         
               sha256Obj.update(fileContents)        
              hexDigest = sha256Obj.hexdigest()               
              tbl.add_row(\[ absPath, fileType, fileSize, humanTimeLastModified, humanTimeLastAccess, humanTimeLastCreated, hexDigest\])
tbl.align = "l" # align the columns left justified

# display the table
print (tbl.get_string(sortby="FileSize", reversesort=True))

I'm trying to list the fileType correctly in PrettyTable.

Your code is not runnable due to syntax errors

Because of the way you walk the directory, you only ever see files rather than directories, links or, indeed, any other file type.
pathlib makes this much easier and is the "modern way". Your code also becomes more concise.
from hashlib import sha256
from time import gmtime, strftime
from pathlib import Path


from prettytable import PrettyTable

FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

targetFolder = input("Enter Target Folder: ")

print("Walking: ", targetFolder, "\n")

tbl = PrettyTable(
    [
        "AbsPath",
        "Type",
        "FileSize",
        "UTC-Modified",
        "UTC-Accessed",
        "UTC-Created",
        "SHA-256 HASH",
    ],
    align="l",
)

for entry in Path(targetFolder).rglob("*"):
    if entry.is_file():
        fileType = "file"
    elif entry.is_dir():
        fileType = "directory"
    elif entry.is_symlink():
        fileType = "symlink"
    else:
        fileType = "unknown"
    stats = entry.stat()
    humanTimeLastModified = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_mtime))
    humanTimeLastAccess = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_atime))
    humanTimeLastCreated = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_ctime))
    hexDigest = sha256(entry.read_bytes()).hexdigest() if entry.is_file() else ""
    tbl.add_row(
        [
            entry.as_posix(),
            fileType,
            stats.st_size,
            humanTimeLastModified,
            humanTimeLastAccess,
            humanTimeLastCreated,
            hexDigest,
        ]
    )

print(tbl.get_string(sortby="FileSize", reversesort=True))


Appreciate the help. I'm about 3 weeks into this as a complete beginner, I haven't used pathlib yet.

I like the solution from @SIGHUP but would do it with pands
import pandas as pd
from hashlib import sha256
from time import gmtime, strftime
from pathlib import Path

FMT = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"

targetFolder = input("Enter Target Folder: ")

print("Walking: ", targetFolder, "\n")

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=
                  [
                      "AbsPath",
                      "Type",
                      "FileSize",
                      "UTC-Modified",
                      "UTC-Accessed",
                      "UTC-Created",
                      "SHA-256 HASH",
                  ])

for entry in Path(targetFolder).rglob("*"):
    if entry.is_file():
        fileType = "file"
    elif entry.is_dir():
        fileType = "directory"
    elif entry.is_symlink():
        fileType = "symlink"
    else:
        fileType = "unknown"
    stats = entry.stat()
    humanTimeLastModified = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_mtime))
    humanTimeLastAccess = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_atime))
    humanTimeLastCreated = strftime(FMT, gmtime(stats.st_ctime))
    hexDigest = sha256(entry.read_bytes()).hexdigest() if entry.is_file() else ""
    row = {"AbsPath": entry.as_posix(),
           "Type" : fileType,
           "FileSize" : stats.st_size,
           "UTC-Modified" : humanTimeLastModified,
           "UTC-Accessed" : humanTimeLastAccess,
           "UTC-Created" : humanTimeLastCreated,
           "SHA-256 HASH" : hexDigest,
          }
    new_df = pd.DataFrame([row])
    df = pd.concat([df,new_df])

df_sorted = df.sort_values(['FileSize'], ascending=[1])
print(df_sorted.to_markdown())

as you can do the output in any format like html, csv, markdown, text...
